# Pythagorean theorem results in negative square

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

Look at this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haNCN.png). To create an expression for y I did the following:

$$y^2+(0.5x)^2=x^2$$
$$y^2+(0.5x)(0.5x)=x^2$$
$$y^2+x^2+x+0.25=x^2$$
$$y^2+x^2+x=x^2-0.25$$
$$y^2+x^2=x^2-x-0.25$$
$$y^2=x^2-x^2-x-0.25$$
$$y^2=-x-0.25$$
$$y=\sqrt{-x-0.25}$$

However, this results in a negative square root.

If I suppose that $x=5$:

$$x^2+2.5^2=5^2$$
$$x^2+6.25=25$$
$$x^2=25-6.25$$
$$x^2=18.75$$
$$x=\sqrt{18.75}$$

Then it works. What did I do wrong? And why did I get a negative square root?

Comment: No. No. No. From the second to the third line, $(0.5x)(0.5x) = 0.25x^2.$

Answer (score 1):

What you did wrong is that you squared $(0.5+x),$ getting $x^2+x+0.25$,

instead of squaring $(0.5x), $ getting $0.25x^2$.

The correct answer would be $y^2+0.25x^2=x^2\implies y^2=0.75x^2\implies y=\dfrac{\sqrt3}2x$.

(Negative or imaginary solutions for $y$ should be rejected.)

Answer (score 0):

$(0.5x)^2=0.25 x^2$ and not $x^2+x+0.25$. It is $(0.5+x)^2=x^2+x+0.25$.